# How to display textbox tag as a value inside textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to initialy display Tag inside textbox, so I write something like this:

```
var resultValue0 = new TextBox()
{
    Location = new Point(x, y),
    Tag = new int[i,j],
    Text = string.Format("({0})", Tag)
};
```

But in result i get only "()" in this textbox. How can I display this properly?

Comment: What is Tag, can you explain us ? ;)

Comment: @CyrilIselin I can represent my TextBox using Tag

Comment: The `asp.net` tag seems to be incorrect, since this is WinForms.

Comment: My bad, I check this as it was suggested, and I'm pretty new to stackoverflow and programming at all.

Comment: When you ask explain clear that what exactly you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

it seems you want to store "(i,j)" inside of Text (now that I read your latest comment).

```
        var resultValue0 = new TextBox()
        {
            Location = new Point(x, y),
            Tag = string.Format("{0},{1}", i, j)
        };
        resultValue0.Text = string.Format("({0})", resultValue0.Tag);
```

Also, I didn't realized before that you were trying to set **Text** inside of the parameters of TextBox using another parameter (**Tag**). That's not possible since Tag was not set yet. If you want to set **resultValue0.Text** using **resultValue0.Tag** you'll need to set Text outside of the parameter section (as above).

Comment: Yes, I want to see in my TextBox something like `(i,j)`. When I changed as you suggest I get `({})`...

Comment: okay... if you want to see something like "(i,j)" that's another thing.. in this example "(i,j)" I dont see any { or }... if you want to display the curly bracket character { or } inside of your string using string.Format, then you'll need to use {{ and }} to display them. that's my answer above. but if you want to display something like "(15,58)" (where i =15 and j=58) then you'd need to write string.Format("({0},{1})", i, j)...

Comment: I made tag out of (i, j) as you can see `Tag = new int[i,j],` so the point is to check if this tag is setting properly depending on loop iteration. Additionally I have more Textboxes in my application (not only in i,j loop) generated dynamicly, and I need to identify it all, to be sure if I generate it properly.

Comment: @Kasia, I just updated my answer

Comment: I also have tested this solution, but it's not working. I temporary solved this by displaying the same value I entered to tag. Now I see, that value is not correctly calculated. Anyway, thanks for an answer!

Answer (score 0):

You said   i get only "()" in this textbox. But you expect to display what ?

If you want text box display "(i,j)" and instead of i will be number :

```
var tb = new TextBox()
{
    Tag = new int[2,4]
};
tb.Text = string.Format("({0},{1})", ( tb.Tag as int[,]).GetUpperBound(0)+1, (tb.Tag as int[,]).GetUpperBound(1)+1);
```